# How to query nested elements in Firebase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase

```
    "John" : {
      "David" : {
        "-KIMA0aPsujdAOpkzP0w" : {
          "message" : "hallu",
          "sender" : "10154053432889835",
          "time" : 1463898873196
        }
      }
    },
    "Harry" : {
      "Christina" : {
        "-KIMA0aPsujdAOpkzP0v" : {
          "message" : "hallu",
          "seen" : true,
          "sender" : "self",
          "time" : 1463898873195
        }
      },
      "Pierce" : {
        "-KILZ_GH7Ji9hQYNK-6p" : {
          "message" : "Eli there.",
          "seen" : true,
          "sender" : "179914035712208",
          "time" : 1463888795301
        },
        "-KIM8yPz2UDOZwHEg_nn" : {
          "message" : "hahjajak",
          "seen" : true,
          "sender" : "self",
          "time" : 1463898597847
        },
}
```

I wanted to query the count of nodes where "seen" key has value "true" of top node which is **John** OR **Harry** There are multiple child node inside it and each child node has multiple child node which has automatic id set.

I just want to know the count of objects which has "seen" key set to **true** and also count of objects which has "seen" key set to **false**

I can extract all the values in node as follows:

```
ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snap in
    for (key,value) in snap.value as! NSDictionary {
    }
    
})
```

I can loop through the dictionary and count the number of objects manually. But that is not too computationally or data efficient as firebase is volume based.

What I want is to know if there is any query to count the number of objects whose "seen" key in root node is "true" or whose "seen" key in root node is "false".

**UPDATE:**

Data Structure

**John**  and **Harry**  are user unique ID. and the node **David** which is immediate child of  **John** node is unique ID of person who the user has chatted with earlier.

And the **KIMA0aPsujdAOpkzP0w** node represent a unique message from user **John** to/from **David**.

So what i wanted was to count the number of messages from **David** to **John** not seen by **John**

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, it's better to paste your actual Firebase Data Structure as text instead of an image. Firebase Console -> Data -> Three dots in upper right, export JSON. The reasons for that is: it's searchable and that we don't have to re-type your structure in an answer.

Comment: Nice suggestion! Updated thank you :)

Comment: Ok. One last thing. You have an ambiguous case; you want to query the count of nodes where 'seen' key has value of true of *top node* which are the two listed. However, those top nodes do not have child nodes of 'seen'. The last part of your question says *count the number of objects whose "seen" key in root node is "true" or whose "seen" key in root node is "false"* but your root node does not have a 'seen' key. I think I know what you are asking but want to make sure. Oh, are you specifically interested in *just* those two top nodes? Can you clarify and update your question?

Comment: Done update as per your suggestion

Comment: I have a similar case, but my data is based on date So I have something like year>months> the uniqueKeyCreatedByFirebase>TheObjectData. I am still stuck with it. Did you find a proper solution for this? My question is here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026092/retrieving-data-from-firebase-while-sorting-it-correctly?noredirect=1#comment71227614_42026092

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only the "seen" value, you should reconsider your database structure and denormalize where possible to make reading as fast as you can.

Keeping your structure to get "seen" value, each time you read you have to get the entire node and loop through it to get the value, downloading unnecessary data, wasting processing time and making overall operation slower.

You should create a new node and store just the "seen" value the way you are going to get it later. Lets say, the best way to structure your database is based on which read operations are going to do and what data do you need in those operations.

You shouldn't worry about duplicating data. Remember that Firebase has the "updateChildren" method that allows you to update data in different nodes in a single operation.

For more info you can read the docs about structuring data here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data

Cheers!

Comment: I totally agree that downloading data and process is not efficient way. That's why I was wondering if firebase has someway of querying this kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the *most* efficient way to handle it, but for a rapid prototype I've been searching for the answer to this problem as well.  I settled on using this strategy to isolate child nodes of the data structure:

```
   ref.observeSingleEventOfType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        for (key,value) in snapshot.value as! NSDictionary {

            if (key as! String == "John/David/etc")
            {
                let newRef  = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("John").child(key as! String)

                newRef.observeSingleEventOfType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

                    for (childKey, childValue) in snapshot.value as! NSDictionary{
                       //do whatever you want with child values/etc
                    }

                })
            }

        }

    })
```

Keep in mind I am VERY new to Firebase on iOS and they just changed their documentation so I'm working through it as I can.  I'm sure there are way better ways to accomplish accessing child data but this worked for my MVP so I went with it.

EDIT:  This assumes that your original reference is aimed at the part of the data tree that you want to target.  For example:

```
   let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("John")
```

That way when you did ref.observeSingle..etc, it would look for the values underneath that child object, instead of the entire tree.