# Retrieving data from firebase while sorting it correctly

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have this structure in my firebase database

```
"metadata" : {
    "2017" : {
      "Februari" : {
        "-Kc3BF0V1iLgtnI65LuR" : {
          "date" : "2017-02-03T13:36:38.311Z",
          "price" : 90
        },
        "-Kc3BF0V1xxfrtnI65OlS" : {
          "date" : "2017-02-03T13:36:38.311Z",
          "price" : 90
        }
      },
      "Januari" : {
        "-Kc3E5bpxpo3RpSHH3fn" : {
          "date" : "2017-01-11T13:50:12.264Z",
          "price" : 45
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

What I am trying to achieve in my app is to show a list like this

```
> Januari
>   - 45 (=price)
> 
> Februari
>   - 90 ()
>   - 240
```

The thing is I am able to show the months, but I can't reach the children because of the unique ID created by firebase.

This is the object I am getting back from firebase

```
e{
    $$conf: Object
    $id: "2017"
    $priority: null
    Februari: Object
        -Kc3BF0V1iLgtnI65LuR: Object
        date: "2017-02-03T13:36:38.311Z"
        price: 90
    Januari: Object
        -Kc3E5bpxpo3RpSHH3fn: Object
        date: "2017-01-11T13:50:12.264Z"
        price: 45
}
```

How would I approach this?

Comment: How do I enter a childNode without having the unique key created by firebase? That's actually my problem :)

Comment: Why don't you retrieve the whole month and all its childs. Push them to an array and and sort it's childs by:

allChilds.sort((a, b) => a.price > b.price);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to use an ng-repeat? Would something like this work for you:

```
<div ng-repeat="(name, month) in months">
    {{ name }}
    <div ng-repeat="entry in month">
        {{ entry.price }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Where months is the result from `database.ref().child('metaData').child('2017');`

Comment: This did the trick for me. But could you clarify me how `{{entry.price}}` worked? Where did I enter object with the unique key created by firebase like `-Kc3BF0V1iLgtnI65LuR`

Comment: It's just looping over an object, you could of done `ng-repeat="(key, entry) in month"` and then had the key as well